# EasyStroke - can't record stroke

Tags: mouse, gestures

I'm trying to record a stroke - ANY stroke, but I can't and after searching and reading all I could find I still can't figure out what's wrong. I press the mouse's middle button (the one I have configured in Preferences -> Behavior -> Gesture Button) and perform a stroke/movement with the mouse, but it doesn't record/reflect it. Nothing happens and from the videos I've watched there should be a trace left from the performed stroke, but nothing happens for me and the Record New Stroke dialog just stays there. I'm clueless as to why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Easystroke **was** a great gesture's app, but it hasn't been actively supported for many years.

There is a small community that's still generating patches to keep it running. See [here](https://github.com/thjaeger/easystroke) for some info.

I stopped using it as it got very difficult to keep up with the patches, and to keep it working.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there's an alternative to it? I mainly need it to make my pen/touchscreen more usable under Ubuntu.

Comment: @kat I'm not aware of one. If you follow the link I gave, you could follow the folks who are trying to keep it alive and functioning... but it'll require some software knowledge on your part... compiling, applying patches, etc.

Comment: @kat If my answer was helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark and up-arrow icons just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: So what is now the way to have gestures in GNOME? (sorry, coming from KDE Plasma where gestures are built-in)